# VS2022 ML.Net Missing cuDNN

Tags: cudnn, ml.net-model-builder

Installing GPU support for ML.Net  Got Cuda 10.1 installed ok but having an issue with cuDNN 7.6.4.
I'm assume it's looking for a path to somewhere but I'm not sure where.
[My training environment configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juezy.png)